# ERROR: Failed building wheel for reportlab

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install a project from git hub and tried to install libraries using requirements.py and for some reason its just giving me this error `ERROR: Failed building wheel for reportlab`,
I don't know much of python just doin this for sake of college project haha.
I am currently using python 3.11

git hub repo I am using : https://github.com/Jawwad-Fida/HealthStack-System/

Comment: I'm seeing the same error as here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2034174#c3 Is that what you're seeing? I don't see how they fixed the issue, though.

Comment: solved the error by removing the dependency from requirements.txt as it wasn't being used anywhere in the project.